# modeling an relationship between sensor values and position (angle and distance) to a target

Tags: matlab, math, modeling

I want to derive a simple model that can predict a current position of an object with respect of a target.

To be more specific, I have a head that has 4 identical light sensors placed between 90 degree. There is a light source (LED) emitting visual light. Since each sensor has angle spectrum (maximum at 90 degree and decrease its sensitivity while the angle of the incident of light increases), the receiving value at each sensor is determined by the angle and distance of the head with respect of the target.

I measured the values at four sensors at various angles and distances.

Each sensor has maximum values around 9.5 when incoming light is low (either the sensor is far from the target or the sensor faces away the target), while the value decreases as the sensor gets close to the target or faces directly toward to the target.

my inputs and outputs look like
[0.1234 0.0124 8.342 9.232]  = [angle, distance]: an example of the head placed toward next to the light.

four inputs from the sensors and two outputs for the angle and distance.

What strategy can I implement to derive an equation that I can use for predicting the angle and distance by putting current incoming sensor values?

I was thinking of multivariate regression, but my outputs are not a single scalar (more of vectors). I am not sure it will work.
Therefore, I am writing here for asking some help.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You will get a lot more help if you post your attempt at implementing your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Your idea about multivariate regression looks reasonable.

IMHO you need to train two models instead of one. The first one will predict angle, and the second one will predict distance.

Why you want to combine these two models? This is looks strange in the sense of the optimization metric. When you build angle model you minimize the error in *radians*. When you build distance model you minimize the error in *meters*. So what the metric you will minimize in single model case?

I believe next links will be useful for you:

1. https://www.mathworks.com/help/curvefit/surface-fitting.html
2. https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/example-curve-fitting-via-optimization.html

Note: in some cases the data normalization (for example via zscore) greatly increases the fitting performance.

P.S. Try also ask at the https://stats.stackexchange.com/